# Issue with baking, can somebody tell me what am i doing wrong

Tags: baking, normal-map

I tried baking this arm sculpt to a low poly model and the normal maps comes out with stripes, also, it has this weird shading. Another issue I'm having is when I switch between eevee and cycles, I'm getting different normal map results. Am i doing something wrong?

[image]

Comment: If you see the UV seams on your model then the colorspace of the normal map is wrong. You have to set it to Non-Color in the Shader Editor.

Comment: Yea, seems do show up, but the problem is with the weird shading and those stripes you can see on the normal map on the right. The seemes are not much of a problem but thats one thing i didnt know so thank you.

Comment: Im also trying to upload model on blendexchange but it stops at around 30% everytime

Comment: Okay so i fixed the shading issues, but this stripe problem is still present

Comment: maybe share this part of your object

Comment: I tried but it would always stop uploading 1/3 of the way trough, i just ended up returning to one of my previous files, did the baking proces and it worked fine. Regarding the issue of normal map changing between cycles and eevee, ive realized restarting blender after baking fixes the issue, so that was just a bug. Either way, thanks for offering to help.